# Report template

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

What information is required to be clear on the performance of the website.Or what listener ,what type of information is needs to be present to third party so that they will know the exact performance of website through a final report.For example transaction per sec,response,crash point and errors,users..Please suggest if i want to make a report of jmeter plan,what should I post into the report so that no questions should arrive back from the client.And please let me know what this figure is about in attached graph?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxKoT.png)And in what cases we are able to know that this issue is arriving due to server system resources constraint.